# PLY 'expression' in grammar causes symbol error

Tags: python, ply

I've been working on some PLY code and in my parser grammar there are certain things that i want "ambiguous". For example, the equivalent to print is show. I don't want show to print only a specific type, instead I want it to print anything, for this I tried to use expression in my grammar but it gives me an error:
Here's my code

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc


reserved = {
  # 'if' : 'IF',
  # 'then' : 'THEN',
  # 'else' : 'ELSE',
  # 'repeat-if' : 'REPEAT-IF',
  'is' : "IS",
  'show' : "SHOW",
  'receive': "RECEIVE"
}

tokens = ['LPAREN','RPAREN','STRING', 'NAME'] + list(reserved.values())

def t_ID(t):
  r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
  t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'NAME')    # Check for reserved words
  return t


t_LPAREN =r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'
t_STRING = r'\".*?\"'
t_ignore = " \t"


def t_error(t):
  print("Syntax error at %s"%t.value)



Variables = {}


def p_receive(p):
  '''statement : NAME IS RECEIVE LPAREN STRING RPAREN'''
  value = input(f"{(p.slice[5].value[1:-1])}")
  Variables[p.slice[1].value]=value

def p_show(p):
  'statement : SHOW LPAREN expression RPAREN '
  value = p.slice[3]
  #TO-DO
  
def p_is(p):
  'statement : NAME IS STRING'
  Variables[p[1]] = p[3]

def p_variable(p):
  'statement : NAME'
  return Variables[p.slice[1].value]

def p_error(p):
  print("Syntax error at %s"%p)

lexer = lex.lex()
yacc.yacc()

with open('CODE.txt','r') as file:
  code = file.read().splitlines()

for line in code:
  try:
    s = line   
  except EOFError:
    break
  yacc.parse(s)
```

And I get the following erro:

```
Symbol 'expression' used, but not defined as a token or a rule
```

However using the PLY example from https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html ,  I never see expression having to be defined

Comment: What do you think `expression : expression PLUS expression` if not (part of) the definition of `expression`?

Comment: I saw that in the example and tried "expression : SHOW LPAREN expression RPAREN " but I get:


WARNING: Symbol 'expression' is unreachable
ERROR: Infinite recursion detected for symbol 'expression'
```

Comment: yes, it's just a part of the definition. As with a recursive function, a recursive grammar production will never terminate by itself; there must be some base case. You can see those a bit further down in the example calculator. I have the feeling that you haven't yet attempted to understand the nature of a context-free grammar. That's far too large a topic for a SO question. The books recommended by Ply's author are excellent; there are also a number of tutorials which are freely available but many of these are of questionable accuracy. If you don't want to buy or borrow a text,...

Comment: ... you could try starting with the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Language-and-Grammar) and perhaps the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). It's not very complicated really, so I'm sure you can figure it out. It's certainly a bit of work. But just copying random snippets out of programs you don't understand is neve a good idea.